# Javascript methods, classes and events

Tags: javascript

how should I document this piece of code:

```
// Is this class?
colors = {

  // Is this method?
  "red" : function() {
     // Do something...
  }

  // Still method?
  "black" : {

     // So what is this?
     "black-1" : function() { /* Do something */ }

   }

}
```

I am using YUI Doc.

These tags **are available**

- @module
- @class
- @method
- @event
- @property

Comment: By the way, there is no official "class" in javascript, but you can make functions that act like classes, supporting the 'new' operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From using YUI, its docs, and a quick skim of the YUI Doc explanation page, it's my impression that it assumes that you're using [the module pattern](http://ajaxian.com/archives/a-javascript-module-pattern).

You don't have a module.

- `colors` => @static @class
- `red` => @method
- `black` => @property
- `black-1` => "internal" (ish) so it's not anything under this taxonomy.